# How do I prevent users from accessing an Office add-in directly in the browser?

Tags: ms-office, office365

Since the Office, in this case, Word, add-in frame is basically a standard web page, how do I prevent users from directly accessing the add-in url in their browser rather than through the actual add-in from the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is purely to 'discourage' your users to use the page outside of the add-in, you could do a JavaScript check to see whether the Office.js has loaded properly (it won't when the host is not an office app), and hide the contents when it is not.

If you want to make it impossible to load the add-in I cannot actually think of a way to do that. There are probably some things in the request header to detect the Office  desktop clients on the server side, but that won't work when using the add-in in a web-based Office app.

Comment: You might also be able to put a query string parameter and use it in the source url ("home.html?office=true), and redirect if you don't see it.  But again, it's only a discouragement (though admittedly I don't see why you'd need anything *more* than a discouragement)